# Rendering an icon if condition is correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render an icon only if `collection.masterAssetId === asset.id`. I am using a getMaster function to find the collection.masterAssetId. The problem that I am having is that the collectionsarr can be undefined in my getMaster function, but also return a number. I have this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'masterAssetId' of undefined`. Would be great if someone could fix this error for me?

Secondly, I am probably making this way too complicated, so feel free to suggest a different approach.

---

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {collections} from "./data.js"
import {assets} from "./data.js"
import {FontAwesome, FaStar} from "react-icons/fa"

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
           collectionsarr: collections,
           assetsarr: assets,
           clickedassets: []
        }
    }

    getMasterId(assetnr){
      const assetnum = ""
      if(this.state.collectionsarr.filter(element => element.masterAssetId === assetnr) === undefined){
        const assetnum = 0
      } else {
        const assetnum = this.state.collectionsarr.filter(element => element.masterAssetId === assetnr)[0].masterAssetId
      }
      return assetnum
    }
  
  render(){
  return (
          <div className="App">
            <h1>Sitecore coding challenge</h1>
            
            <div className="left">
              {this.state.collectionsarr.map(element => 
                <div key={element.id}>
                  <p onClick={()=>this.handleAssetsClick(element.id)}>{element.name}</p>
                  <img src={this.getAssetPath(element.masterAssetId)} alt="pic"/>
                  <br></br>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>

            <div className="right">
                {this.state.clickedassets.map(asset => 
                  <div key={asset.id}>
                    <img src={require(`./${asset.path}`)} alt="pic"/>
                    <p>{asset.name}</p>
                    <p>{asset.id}</p>
                    <button onClick={() => this.makeMaster(asset.id)}>Make master!</button>
                    <p>icon "this is the master</p>
                    
                    {asset.id === this.getMasterId(asset.id) && <FaStar />}
                    
                    <br></br>
                  </div>
                )}
            </div>
          </div>
        )
  }
}

export default App
```

---

data.js

```
const collections = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "The Simpsons",
        masterAssetId: 13,
        tags: {
            name: "Cartoon",
            subTag: {
                name: "Simpsons family",
                subTag: {
                    name: "2014",
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Super heroes",
        masterAssetId: 24,
        tags: {
            name: "DC Super heroes",
            subTag: {
                name: "2014",
            },
        },
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Toy story",
        masterAssetId: 31,
        tags: {
            name: "Disney",
            subTag: {
                name: "Pixar",
                subTag: {
                    name: "Original movie",
                    subTag: {
                        name: "2010",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Ninjago",
        masterAssetId: 42,
        tags: {
            name: "Ninja",
            subTag: {
                name: "Secret Ninja Force",
                subTag: {
                    name: "2017",
                },
            },
        },
    },
];

const assets = [
    {
        id: 11,
        name: "Homer Simpson",
        path: "Homer.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        name: "Lisa Simpson",
        path: "Lisa.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        name: "Bart Simpson",
        path: "Bart.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        name: "Marge Simpson",
        path: "Marge.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        name: "Grampa Simpson",
        path: "Grampa.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 16,
        name: "Maggie Simpson",
        path: "Maggie.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 21,
        name: "Green Lantern",
        path: "Green lantern.jpg",
        collectionId: 2,
    }
];
```

Comment: So check if `masterAssetId` is defined first?

Comment: that's what I'm doing in my getMasterId code right?

Comment: Can you try `let assetnum = ""` instead of `const assetnum = ""` and get rid of `const` next to `assetnum =...` inside the conditionals?

Comment: thanks good point, changed it. But still get: App.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'masterAssetId' of undefined
    at App.getMasterId (App.js:48)

Answer (score 0):

Is the collections data being set properly?  What's the console.log() output of the state at render?

At any rate, I think the better approach for setting state is to do it in componentDidMount() lifecycle method:

```
import {getCollection} from "./data.js";
 
state = {
  collectionsarr: [],
  assetsarr: [],
  clickedassets: []

},

componentDidMount = () => {
   this.setState({
      collectionsarr: getCollection()
   });
}
```

data.js:

```
const collections = [...];

export function getCollection() {
   return collections; 
}
```

Comment: yes the collections data is set properly, I had left out the exports. Could you please have a look at the getMasterId function?

Comment: hmm ic, please try doing let assetnum;   then set it's value just as assetnum = ...

const is for setting objects that should be immutable

Comment: what is the state in the getMasterId function?

Answer (score 0):

Change your getMasterId function

```
showIcon(assetnr) {     
  let index = (this.state.collectionsarr || []).findIndex(item => {
    return item.masterAssetId === assetnr;
  })

  return index != -1;
}
```

This function will return true if assetId === masterId then You can render it as

```
{this.showIcon(asset.id) && <FaStar />}
```